# How to throw a file to download for users using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I have code, it download the file with rename it on button click, but it start download on my server, I want it to throw the file to download for users, as we download file from other server/websites, how to do this, please help me.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {
     //File to save the contents to
    $fp = fopen ('files2.tar', 'w+');
    $url = "http://localhost/files.tar";
    //Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
    $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));
    //give curl the file pointer so that it can write to it
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response
    //done
    curl_close($ch);
   }

  ?>


<form method="POST">
   <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following headers after you get the curl response from server to force file download:

```
`header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
 header('Cache-Control: private', false);
 header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($url) . '"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
 header('Connection: close');`
```

Comment: I do not want force download, and it should be on click of button, how do I do that, pls can you update your answer a little bit.

Comment: I see you have added the HTML button. After you click it, cURL will get the file and download it if you use the header codes I have mentioned above.